# Customized html escaping with Jinja2

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

There are a variety of ways that it can be useful to make some transformation when escaping user-generated text before displaying it as html.  For example, one might want to convert newlines to `<br/>`, "linkify" urls, replace spaces with `&nbsp;`'s, etc.

Typical recommendations for how to do this type of transformation involve first escaping the text and then making the appropriate substitutions after-the-fact.  For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14795104 (that one is for Mako rather than Jinja2 but they both seem to use markupsafe for escaping) suggests to pass already-escaped text into the function and then to call `s.replace("\n", Markup("<br />"))`.  However, these recommendations seem somewhat fragile - they assume that the escaping process won't introduce any of the characters to be replaced, and they don't work too well when "chained".  For example, if you first converted urls to links and then attempted to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`'s, you might wind up with something like `<a&nbsp;href=...`.

It seems like the more "correct" way to handle this would be for the escaping function to take some kind of transformation function as a parameter to allow the text to be translated as part of the escaping process.  Is there an existing way to do this in Jinja2?